# In Haskell, why do I need to specify the typeclass in an instance declaration?

Tags: haskell

The following doesn't compile:

```
data Point a b = Point { x :: a
                       , y :: b
                       } deriving (Show)

instance Eq (Point a b) where
  (Point x _) == (Point y _) = x == y
```

The error is:

```
No instance for (Eq a)
  arising from a use of `=='
In the expression: x == y
In an equation for `==': (Point x _) == (Point y _) = x == y
In the instance declaration for `Eq (Point a b)'
```

However, if I add the typeclass into the instance, then it works:

```
data Point a b = Point { x :: a
                       , y :: b
                       } deriving (Show)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Point a b) where
  (Point x _) == (Point y _) = x == y
```

Can't the compiler see that I'm using `a == a` in there and deduce that `a` must be in the typeclass `Eq`?

Comment: Your `Eq` instance declaration looks fishy to me. Aside from whatever your code says to the *compiler*, it says to the *world* that the second component of a point *doesn't matter*, except perhaps for some internal optimization purpose. Your `Show` instance, on the other hand, says the opposite, that *both* components matter.

Comment: If the second component really *doesn't* matter, then you shouldn't derive `Show`, but should instead do something vaguely like `instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (Point a b) where showsPrec _ (Point x y) s = "Point " ++ shows x` and then, for debugging, write your own function `showDirtyLaundry (Point a b) = "Point "++show a++show b`. If, however, the second component matters to the rest of the world, you should instead use `deriving (Eq, Show)` and make everything clearer. There may also be efficiency benefits to using `deriving` in some cases, so use it whenever it's appropriate.

Answer (score 15):

It *can* deuce that `a` must be in the type class `Eq`. That's exactly why it's complaining. You declared `instance Eq (Point a b)`, which says that types of the form `Point a b` are in the `Eq` type class for *any* types `a` and `b`, but you gave a definition for `==` that only works when `a` is a member of `Eq`.

Those two things are inconsistent, so Haskell doesn't try to guess which one is what you really meant, it just reports it as an error. The language didn't *have* to work that way, but it's a deliberate design choice.

Comment: Is there any way for me to write the code above without writing `Eq a`?

Comment: @Eyal No, unless you want your Eq to be more standard (ie, use the y record), in which case you could derive Eq

Comment: @Eyal: No.  Why would you want to?

Comment: @Eyal: If this were allowed, it would make it harder to determine what constraints you need on arguments given to the type class method for a given instance. If you're required to put the constraints in the instance head, all you have to do is look at the first line of the instance definition. If you *weren't* required, you would pretty much be lying about the actual type in the instance head, because something like `Point a b` (with no constraints) implies that this works for all types `a` and `b` in Haskell.

Comment: @alternative: the derived instance of Eq for `Point a b` will have Eq constraints for both `a` and `b`, so you aren't *really* avoiding it.

Comment: @DavidYoung "harder to determine" isn't a good argument.  It's actually really easy to determine if my code follows constraints: I try to compile it.  For functions, it's easy to see if I got it right.  However, for typeclasses, Haskell requires me to be explicit.  Why?  Is it something fundamental to algebraic data types or is it an implementation detail of Haskell?

Comment: @Eyal It's not an implementation detail, it's a *design decision*, as I said in my answer. Saying something like `instance Eq where ... == ...` and having Haskell work out what instance you're declaring from the implementation would not be impossible to implement in at least some cases (although many cases, especially involving default definitions, would be ambiguous and require a more explicit declaration to get the right instance). The Haskell designers *chose* to require that when you declare an instance you say what types the instance is for.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine a function

```
equals ::  a -> a -> Bool
equals = (==)
```

The compiler can obviously infer that the type of equals should be `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`. But it errors, because you declared that your type works for all a.

Typeclass instances are similar, except we don't have the option of letting them being inferred in the same way we could leave out the type declaration for `equals`. So it is necessary to specificy the constraint in the same way that if you specify the type signature of a function, you also have to specify the constraint.

That is, ghc won't infer *only* the constraint; it either has to infer the entire signature, or none of it. (Well, it infers either way, but the inference has to be more general than what you typed it as, if you typed it - and contraints fall under this requirement).

Think of your initial `instance Eq (Point a b)` as `(==) :: (Point a b) -> (Point a b) -> Bool`, which is impossible to well-define in the way that you like, since giving it that body would have `(==) :: Eq a => (Point a b) -> (Point a b) -> Bool`.

Comment: You write that typeclass instances don't have the option of letting them be inferred as do function.  Why not?  Is there something in lambda calculus or algebraic type systems that makes it impossible?  Or did the Haskell designers simply leave it out?